# Why SDM gives error while downloading from dream spark periodically?

Tags: download, dreamspark

I've been trying to download Windows 8.1 for a week.Every time i start a download, it stops at 15-20% and gives the following error:

"The download cannot be completed. If a location selection is available for this product, select another location. If no location selection is available, the download may fail to complete because no Internet connection was found, the Internet connection was lost or a firewall or proxy server exists between the client station and hosting location. Please try again later".

When I click on resume download after this error,it starts again but gives same error after some time but starts again by resuming.

When download finishes, it gives unpacking error and suggests to download the product again.
It has happened so many times (with some of my friends as well), I'm very frustrated, is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Is your laptop going to sleep part way through the download?